# How do change chartYvalues?

Tags: swiftui, ios16, swiftui-charts

Please tell me how to change these values? I need a chart that will display price changes. Since the spread is small I want to make a zoom, for example from 18.0 to 20.0. How do I change this?

[image: This values.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the `.chartYScale` modifier:

```swift
Chart {
    //your chart stuff here
}
.chartYScale(domain: 18...20)
```